# How to get object id of user which need to be add in resource group which is running in loop

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform

I have above terraform which will create resource group from csv list and run loop, its showing me error, as object id is not reading.
Any idea how to add owner to resource group created in loop in terraform?

```
locals {
project_info = csvdecode(test.csv)
}

module "azurerm_resource_group" {
  for_each = { for proj in local.project_info : proj.project_name => proj }
  source = "../../../modules/azurerm_resource_group"
  project_name = each.value.project_name
  tags = {
    costcenter     = ""
    expiration     = each.value.end_date
    owner          = each.value.project_owner
    project        = each.value.project_name
}

}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get Object ID of Owner
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data "azuread_user" "owner" {
  for_each            = module.azurerm_resource_group
  user_principal_name = lookup(each.value.resourcegroup_tags, "owner")
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Assign RG owner access to owner of this project
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

module "azurerm_role_assignment" {
  source = "../../../modules/azurerm_role_assignment"
  for_each             = module.azurerm_resource_group
  scope_id             = each.value.id
  role_definition_name = "Owner"
  principal_id         = values(data.azuread_user.owner)[*].object_id
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Also, have you defined an output in the module?

Comment: Yes, output is defined like this 
@MarkoE
 output "resource_group_id" {
  value       = values(module.azurerm_resource_group)[*].id
}

Comment: Issue is every project has owner, and I want to run that csv in loop, when resource group create it should add owner to that resource group, all this is in loop, now when I tried to add owner in role assignment, it is not getting read.

Comment: Its working now, I have added output of data and in role assignment used principal id like "principal_id         = data.azuread_user.owner[each.key].object_id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
module "azurerm_role_assignment" {
  source = "../../../modules/azurerm_role_assignment"
  for_each             = module.azurerm_resource_group
  scope_id             = each.value.id
  role_definition_name = "Owner"
  principal_id         = "${data.azuread_user.owner[each.key].object_id}
}
```

Share with me the error if it doesn't work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This object does not have an attribute named "object_id". This error I got when I used above command

Comment: I edit the answer with your solution